# Restructuring a Gamble database for comparison

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

For a side project i'm looking at comparing odds of 2 betting agencies and having some trouble to put this information in the right format in my table.

Currently i have the following table:

| Provider | BettingType | OutcomeLabel | Odds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Agency A | A | Higher than 1.5 | 1.3 |
| Agency A | A | Lower than 1.5 | 1.6 |
| Agency A | B | Yes | 2.3 |
| Agency A | B | No | 1.2 |
| Agency B | A | Higher than 1.5 | 1.1 |
| Agency B | A | Lower than 1.5 | 1.8 |
| Agency B | B | Yes | 1.5 |
| Agency B | B | No | 1.3 |

What i want is to transform this table in a way that the rows look like this:

| Provider | BettingType | OutcomeLabel | Odds | OppositeProvider | OppositeOutcomeLabel | OppositeOdds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Agency A | A | Higher than 1.5 | 1.3 | Agency B | Lower than 1.5 | 1.8 |
| Agency A | A | Lower than 1.5 | 1.6 | Agency B | Higher than 1.5 | 1.1 |
| Agency A | B | Yes | 2.3 | Agency B | No | 1.3 |
| Agency A | B | No | 1.2 | Agency B | Yes | 1.5 |

This transformation cuts half of the rows and pastes these as column. Is important to notice that the OppositeOutcomeLabel here is the Opposite of the OutcomeLabel (Naming gives it away but thought I'd highlight it).

I did some prework but can't seem to figure out the last step. Any help would be amazing!

The example below is just a subset of the data. I'm looking for a dynamic solution that is extendable towards the future (besides specifying the opposites)

Thanks in advance

```
data = {
    'Provider': ['Agency A', 'Agency A', 'Agency A', 'Agency A', 'Agency B', 'Agency B', 'Agency B', 'Agency B'],
    'MainBet': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
    'OutcomeLabel': ['Higher than 1.5', 'Lower than 1.5', 'Yes', 'No', 'Higher than 1.5', 'Lower than 1.5', 'Yes', 'No'],
    'Odds': [2.0, 3.0, 1.5, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a dictionary to map OutcomeLabel to its opposite
opposite_outcome_label = {
    'Higher than 1.5': 'Lower than 1.5',
    'Lower than 1.5': 'Higher than 1.5',
    'Yes': 'No',
    'NO': 'Yes'
}

# Create a dictionary to map Provider to its opposite
opposite_provider = {
    'Agency A': 'Agency B',
    'Agency B': 'Agency A'
}

# Function to get opposite OutcomeLabel
def get_opposite_outcome(row):
    return opposite_outcome_label.get(row['OutcomeLabel'])


# Function to get opposite Provider
def get_opposite_provider(row):
    return opposite_provider.get(row['Provider'])

# Apply the functions to create OppositeOutcome and OppositeProvider columns
df['OppositeOutcome'] = df.apply(get_opposite_outcome, axis=1)
df['OppositeProvider'] = df.apply(get_opposite_provider, axis=1)
```

Comment: so you want to select row by 1) "Provider" *not equal*, 2) "Betting type" *equal* and 3) "Outcome label" *opposite* -that might require a dictionary, to specify what is opposite to what,

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
opposite_outcome_label = {
    "Higher than 1.5": "Lower than 1.5",
    "Lower than 1.5": "Higher than 1.5",
    "Yes": "No",
    "No": "Yes",
}

(i1, g1), (i2, g2) = df.groupby("Provider")

# swap in case Agency B is first
if i1 == "Agency B":
    i1, g1, i2, g2 = i2, g2, i1, g1

# sort g1 according keys of `opposite_outcome_label`
g1 = g1.sort_values(
    by="OutcomeLabel",
    key=lambda series, l=list(opposite_outcome_label): [l.index(v) for v in series],
)

# sort g2 according values of `opposite_outcome_label`
g2 = g2.sort_values(
    by="OutcomeLabel",
    key=lambda series, l=list(opposite_outcome_label.values()): [
        l.index(v) for v in series
    ],
)

out = pd.concat(
    [g1.reset_index(drop=True), g2.add_prefix("Opposite").reset_index(drop=True)],
    axis=1,
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
   Provider BettingType     OutcomeLabel  Odds OppositeProvider OppositeBettingType OppositeOutcomeLabel  OppositeOdds
0  Agency A           A  Higher than 1.5   1.3         Agency B                   A       Lower than 1.5           1.8
1  Agency A           A   Lower than 1.5   1.6         Agency B                   A      Higher than 1.5           1.1
2  Agency A           B              Yes   2.3         Agency B                   B                   No           1.3
3  Agency A           B               No   1.2         Agency B                   B                  Yes           1.5
```